# Angular Material Table data from FLASK API

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am struggling to understand the next step I need to do to connect my data from an FLASK API to an Angular Material Table. I started by creating the table component by running

```
ng g @angular/material:material-table --name=log-modal
```

The end goal is to have the table appears in a modal, which is pop-up when a user clicks on a button in the app component called "View Logs". I have figured out how to pull in the data in the format i need, but not sure what needs to be done, to get this data into the **EXAMPLE_DATA** array in the datasource.ts

Many Thanks

Please see code below

**app.ts**

```
getLogs() {
    this.dataService.getLogs(this.searchValue).subscribe(
      data =>  {
        this.logList = [];
        for(var x=0; x < data.data.length; x++) {
          this.logList.push({
            Name: data.data[x][0],
            Time: data.data[x][1],
            File: data.data[x][2],
            Date: data.data[x][3],
          })
        }     
      },
    );
  }

  openDialog() {
    this.getLogs();
    this.modalService.open(LogModalComponent);
  }
```

**The api returns**

```
{
    "Name": "name1",
    "Time": "11:23:28",
    "File": "File1",
    "Date": "01-01-2022"
}
```

**app.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="float: left; font-size: 18px" (click)="openDialog()">View Logs</button>
```

**log-modal.ts**

```
export class LogModalComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable, {static: false}) table: MatTable<LogModalItem>;
  dataSource: LogModalDataSource;

  @Input() CurrentLog: any = [];

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['name', 'time', 'file', 'date'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new LogModalDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

**log-modal.html**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8 data-table">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="time">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>time</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.time}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="file">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>file</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.file}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>date</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.date}}</td>
    </ng-container>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="5"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**log-modal-datasource.ts**

```
export interface LogModalItem {
  username: string;
  time: string;
  filename: string;
  startdate: string;
  tableupdated: string;
  status: string;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: LogModalItem[] = []  //unsure how to add my data here
;
```

Comment: I see some issues in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your app.ts, move the

```
 this.modalService.open(LogModalComponent);
```

into your getLogs call and notice the change to open the modal while passing the data:

```
getLogs() {
    this.dataService.getLogs(this.searchValue).subscribe(
      data =>  {
        this.logList = [];
        for(var x=0; x < data.data.length; x++) {
          this.logList.push({
            Name: data.data[x][0],
            Time: data.data[x][1],
            File: data.data[x][2],
            Date: data.data[x][3],
          })
        } 
       
         this.modalService.open(LogModalComponent, data: {list: this.logList});    
      },
    );
  }
```

And then inside of your log-modal.ts, you need to inject the data into the constructor like this:

```
 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any){
this.CurrentLog = data.list;
}
```

That should get the data into the modal for you and ready to use in your table. You then just need to set that data to your datasource.

You also have the option of loading the data in the modal, but that would change a few parts of your code and it can get a bit more complicated.

Comment: This is the right way